# «Казалось» — в конкретном предложении. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, тире, синтаксический-разбор, вводные-слова

> Она обогнула гараж и увидела, как пацан бежит по направлению к дому, стоящему по диагонали от второго. Автоматически отметила на нем шестой номер. Прибавила скорость. Когда она схватила пацана за рукав легкой курточки, она даже не запыхалась.
> — Далеко собрался?
> *У пацана пот катился градом по лицу, он тяжело дышал, посинел, **казалось,** еще немного и он задохнется.* Женя на секунду удивилась — они пробежали всего ничего, откуда такая реакция у маленького мальчика?
> [А. Миронова. И дам вам сердце новое](https://www.rulit.me/books/i-dam-vam-serdce-novoe-read-497056-7.html)

Смущает меня пунктуация (очень хочется поставить тире). И ещё: не могу понять — является ли слово "казалось" вводным или членом предложения?
Поделитесь своим видением: каков статус "казалось" и правильна ли пунктуация?

Answer (score 5):

Вместо запятой перед "казалось" стоило бы, по-моему, поставить какой-либо более сильный разделяющий знак (но и варианты с запятой часто встречаются. См.: [***Несколько месяцев они занимались каждый день без перерывов, успех был ощутим, казалось, еще совсем чуть-чуть, и можно будет, забыв про ...***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=tCcfDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT80&lpg=PT80&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=Onhk5x7r0r&sig=ACfU3U1T0kJebXagI4Yp0J0-CYDnZGM9JA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio05qd5dDhAhUjwqYKHWr-BA0Q6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%22&f=false)).

Возможные варианты:

***У пацана пот катился градом по лицу, он тяжело дышал, посинел; казалось, еще немного (—,) и он задохнется.***

***У пацана пот катился градом по лицу, он тяжело дышал, посинел… Казалось, еще немного (—,) и он задохнется.***

По поводу знака после "немного"...

***Ещё немного (—,) и он задохнется*** — предложение сложносочинённое, части его должны быть разделены **либо запятой, либо тире**.

Ср. с примером у Розенталя:

[***Ещё немного (— ,) и мы оказались бы на краю пропасти.***](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=190)

.

Что же до того, чем считать в этом предложении словоформу "казалось" — вводным словом или же сказуемым… Полагаю, ни один из этих вариантов не будет неправильным. Переходный случай. Находясь в начале предложения, "казалось" является синкретичной словоформой, в которой совмещаются и признаки модального, и признаки знаменательного слова.

Вот что, к примеру, говорит о подобных случаях **Лидия Дмитриевна Чеснокова** (**Русский язык. Трудные случаи морфологического разбора**. — М., 1991):

> Например, в предложении ***Кажется***, шепчут колосья друг другу:
>   скучно нам слушать осеннюю вьюгу (Н.) слово *кажется* может быть
>   квалифицировано и как модальное вводное слово, и как глагол-сказуемое
>   в сложном предложении… **При анализе подобных случаев не следует
>   стремиться к однозначному ответу, указание на возможность двоякой
>   квалификации — лучший показатель овладения материалом.**

Comment: Вопрос о предложении: " ...казалось, еще немного и он задохнется". Вводное слово здесь разве не является общим элементом для двух предложений при наличии союза И? В этом случае запятая не ставится.Розенталь: Короче говоря, экзамены кончились и начались каникулы; Вероятно, у автора по этой причине нет запятой.

Comment: _Sharon: Вводное слово здесь разве не является общим элементом для двух предложений при наличии союза И?_ === Думаю, не является.  Разбейте   приведённое Вами предложение из Розенталя на части: _Короче говоря, экзамены кончились. Короче говоря, начались каникулы_. Вводное легко вписывается в каждую из этих частей, и даже если выкинуть какую-либо из этих частей, вводное сохранится. А теперь попробуйте сделать то же самое с разбираемым нами предложением...

Comment: А я думаю, что относится, и прежде всего по смыслу. Казалось, что еще немного и он задохнется. Это всё казалось персонажу. Это как раз тот случай, когда вводное слово определяет ирреальную модальность обоих предложений. Формальные разбивки здесь ничего не дают. Розенталь ничего не разбивает, в его примерах делается смысловой анализ относительно принадлежности вводного слова одному или двум предложениям.

Answer (score 2):

***У пацана пот катился градом по лицу, он тяжело дышал, посинел; казалось, еще немного и он задохнется.*** Женя на секунду удивилась — они пробежали всего ничего, откуда такая реакция у маленького мальчика?

**Пояснение**

Две ситуации надо разделить интонационно и знаком препинания. (Запятая с этим не справляется, нужно знак посильнее).

Тире  имеет присоединительный характер, а два эти сообщения лучше сделать равноправными.

Делить текст на два предложения не стоит, а **точка с запятой** как раз подойдет, так как две части предложения имеют собственные знаки. Кроме того, в этом случае **вводное слово** однозначно отходит ко второй части предложения.

Тире нежелательно еще и потому, что в следующем предложении тоже есть тире.

***Казалось*** — вводное слово, не сказуемое. Сказуемым оно будет при наличии изъяснительного союза: *казалось, что*...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92432/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).