# Надо ли превращать вводное слово в сказуемое?

Tags: грамматика, вводные-слова

**Надо ли считать вводное слово сказуемым?**

Именно это предлагается нам сделать, что видно из следующего текста: "В предложении *Кажется, шепчут колосья друг другу: скучно нам слушать осеннюю вьюгу* (Н.) слово *кажется* может быть квалифицировано и как модальное вводное слово, и как глагол-сказуемое в сложном предложении… Находясь в начале предложения, "казалось" является синкретичной словоформой, в которой совмещаются **и признаки модального, и признаки знаменательного слова.** (Л. Чеснокова).

Материал из ответа на вопрос [«Казалось» — в конкретном предложении. Пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450455/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Короткий ответ будет такой: этого, как я думаю,  делать нельзя. **Не модальность, а структурная грамматика определяет статус вводного слова.**

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

**1) Итак, надо ли превращать вводное слово в сказуемое?**

Практический смысл вопроса заключается в том, чтобы понять **новое качество вводного слова** и определить его  именно как вводное слово,  а не как сказуемое или обстоятельство.

2) Вводные слова как особый лексико-грамматический класс появились **не очень давно**  В первой академической грамматике М.В. Ломоносова 1755 года  такое понятие, как «вводное слово» отсутствует. (Большинство вводных слов М.В. Ломоносов относит к наречиям).  Впервые вводные слова  упомянуты в «Русской грамматике» А.Х. Востокова в 1831 году.  **Признаком вводных слов считалось то, что они грамматически не были связаны с предложением, а были выведены за пределы предикативной единицы.**
http://flatik.ru/iz-istorii-izucheniya-vvodnih-slov-voprosi-terminologii

А вот **модальность** вводных слов изучалась уже на следующем этапе, **основным же признаком вводных слов остается отсутствие грамматической связи с предложением**.

3) Как известно, вводные слова **по происхождению чаще всего соотносятся с глаголами, падежными формами существительных и наречиями.** Что же происходит с этими формами, как они приобретают статус вводных слов (как они выводятся из состава предложения)? Рассмотрим для примера три вводных слова: ***к счастью,  в конце концов, казалось.***

4) Вводную форму ***к счастью*** легко отличить от исходного существительного: Посуда бьется (к чему?)  к счастью. – Чашка не разбилась, к счастью. Или: Чашка, к счастью,  не разбилась.

Чтобы стать вводным словом,  существительное теряет связь с исходной конструкцией, например: Так сложилось (к чему?) к счастью, что чашка не разбилась.  Кроме того, вводное слово получает возможность занимать свободную позицию в предложении.

5) А вот наречие ***в конце концов*** труднее отличить от вводного слова, так как они составляют пару обстоятельство – вводное слово. Структура предложения в этом случае может не меняться, что связано с относительно свободной позицией наречия в предложении, хотя тоже учитывается при анализе. Но теперь уже приходится анализировать **и семантику слова.**

6) И наконец, глагольная форма ***казалось***. Для вводного слова казалось исходная конструкция выглядит так:  ***Казалось, что всё еще может измениться.  – (1) КазаАлось, //всё еще может изменИться.  Или:  (2) ВсЁ, казалось, //ещё может изменИться.***

Преобразования  происходят такие: убирается союз ЧТО, вводное слово может занимать свободную позицию в предложении.

А чем **отличаются по смыслу** предложения (1) и (2)? Всё различие состоит в том,  что у них **разное актуальное членение.** В предложении (1) ударение падает на вводное слово, а в предложении (2) безударное вводное слово составляет одну фразу с ударным местоимением *всё*.

7) Ударная позиция вводного слова **подчеркивает его значимость,** однако это единственная разница между этими предложениями.

**Но можно ли считать это поводом для того, чтобы  менять статус вводного слова, превращая его в сказуемое, и при этом искусственно отыскивать утерянную грамматическую связь с предложением** (взамен опущенного союза ЧТО).

Нужно ли **возвращаться назад к тому времени**, когда в грамматике еще не был выделен особый класс вводных слов?

Тематика вводных слов в настоящее время расширена, к ним относятся не только модальные слова, но и те, которые используются для оформления предложения. **Поэтому не семантика, а именно грамматический статус является основным показателем для этого класса грамматических слов.**

Comment: TL; DR... Шутка) Обязательно прочитаю внимательно, в данный момент усидчивости не хватает. :) ***Спасибо за вопрос!*** Сам не созрел с формулировкой. У меня бы всё равно так не получилось, теоретических знаний нет таких глубоких. ;)

Comment: Спасибо, Артем за отзыв. Я тоже не специалист по этой теме, а все знания соответствуют базовому уровню. Мне просто хотелось сказать, что надо объективно оценивать все новые идеи, которые нам предлагают.  Для понимания этого класса слов пройден долгий исторический путь, а теперь нас зовут обратно, " в синкретичность."